# Short-hand OCaml "type equality"

Tags: ocaml

Is there a short-hand OCaml notation for a function that could be implemented like this:

```
match e with
  Mycons ( _ ) -> true
  | _ -> false
```

I was thinking along the lines of `typeof(e) == Mycons` but i didn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a shorter notation:

```
let isMycons a = function | Mycons(_) -> true | _ -> false
```

Is a one liner and as elegant as a match.

Answer (score 6):

I've often wanted something like this, though "type equality" is not a good name for it (IMHO). `Mycons` is a value constructor; it represents a value not a type. For nullary constructors you can use something like `((=) None)`, but other than this I haven't found a more concise way to write it.

Comment: Pierre Weis wanted to implement a compact notation for something similar to this. His idea was that `record.field`, `Module.value`, `Module.Module` were taken but `value.Constructor` remained available to denote the argument(s) of `value` if `value` was a `Constructor`. I presume this notation would have returned `()` if `value` was the 0-ary constructor `Constructor` and raised an exception if it wasn't.

Comment: Good point, I was also quite annoyed by calling it "type inequality" since that was a constructor thing.